# How to attach files, which were saved in DriveHQ in Rails mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ftp

In my application i have a file upload option. The uploaded files used to saved in DriveHQ ftp server. After uploading i want to send a mail to the admin with the uploaded file as attachment.

I tried as follows

```
 uri = URI::FTP.build(['username:password', 'ftp.drivehq.com', nil,"\\My Documents\\#{17}\\Fitness.txt", 'i'])
```

And in the mailer:

```
 attachments['image'] = {mime_type: 'text/plain',content: File.read(uri)}
```

But its not working. it was returning error as

```
 bad component(expected relative path component): \My Documents\17\Fitness.txt;type=i
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using the API in a wrong way.

You need to download the file, and yes you do it by creating an URI to the FTP server, but then you need to download the file to a temporary directory.

After that, in your mailer you read that file.

Remember since File is a subclass of `IO` and it does not have the read method, when you invoke File.read, you are actually calling `IO.read`.